# Continuous strictly increasing function with derivative infinity at a measure 0 set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset [0,1]$ with $\mu(E)=0$. Does there exist a continuous, strictly increasing function $f$ on $[0,1]$ so that $f'(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in E$ (in Lebesgue sense)?

I think there exist such a function, but I don't know how to construct.

Comment: Is E given and you want to construct f or do you just need an example of such an E and f? Do you expect something from f? Differentiable everywhere away feom E ...?

Comment: @user3808066 E is given and I need to construct an f for it. f is differentiable at every points since it is a strictly increasing function.

Comment: Strictly increasing only implies allmost everywhere differentiability. You can have edges.

Comment: And what does the in "Lebesque sense" mean? It is allready a condition on a zero set.

Comment: @user3808066 Differentiable here means that the upper left, upper right, lower left and lower right difference are all the same. Maybe we use different definition.

Comment: That was my question. In that case I could show it if E was countable.

Comment: And I think it should be possible to show that it is not true for, for example the cantor set but I still didn't figure out how.

Comment: See [my 18 April 2007 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5661065) (follow-up comment [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5661116)) and the stackexchange question [Absolute continuous function with given set of discontinuities of derivatives.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567840/absolute-continuous-function-with-given-set-of-discontinuities-of-derivatives).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure how the general case works but if $E$ is countable consider $E=\{q_n\;:\;n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and take $f$ a function which is $0$ on $(-\infty,-1/2]$, $1$ on $[1/2,\infty)$, monotonic and has a derivative $f':\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty]$ with $f'(0)=\infty$, additionally take a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \ell^1$, $a_n>0$. Then the function
$$
 g(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_nf(x-q_n)
$$
 is continuous and monotone. Further since for all $n$ $a_nf'(x-q_n)$ is a non negative function
$$
 g(x) = \int_{-1}^x \sum_n a_n f'(s-q_n)\mathrm{d}s
$$
and hence at every $q_m$ 
$$
 g'(x) = f'(0) + \sum_{n\not= m} f'(q_m-q_n) =\infty.
$$